# Using a script someone else made in Google Docs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, security

I was looking for a script to add to a Google Doc that would automatically insert the current date into the document. I found the script on this page.  The last step is to authorize the script and when you do that this comes up:

> This will allow Date Macro to: View and manage your Google Docs documents Make sure you trust Date Macro You may be sharing sensitive
>   info with this site or app. Learn about how Date Macro will handle
>   your data by reviewing its terms of service and privacy policies. You
>   can always see or remove access in your Google Account. Learn about
>   the risks

So, I am not sure how to proceed.  I cannot see anything malicious in the text/script but I do very much want to protect the document that I want the auto-date to appear on.

So, how do I know who/what I am *really* giving access to when I authorize the script?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't see anything out of order in such script/macro then you are good to ignore all warnings which pop up. It's not like Google scans them and alert you that it found malicious string/command. These kinds of warnings apply almost on all scripts and it's meant to be something like a friendly reminder/warning even though they look like "alerts of found malware".

All your approvals can be found and retracted anytime under **Third-party access** at:
**https://myaccount.google.com/security-checkup?utm_source=google-account&utm_medium=web&continue=https://myaccount.google.com/**

[image: 0]